# Debugging Chrome Extension in VS Code throws 'Cannot connect to the target' error

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a Chrome Extension in VS Code using 'Attach to Chrome' configuration. However, when I run the debugger, it throws an error: "Cannot connect to the target at localhost:9222: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:9222: Could not find any debuggable target".

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp7HO.png)

Here is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "chrome",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "url": "https://github.com/",
    },
  ]
}
```

My manifest.json file includes the necessary content script and background script:

```json
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "description": "Some description",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
          "http://*/*",
          "https://*/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "js": [
          "content_script.js"
        ]
    }],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "runtimeArgs": ["--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}"]
}
```

I have set the correct port number (9222) in my launch.json configuration file and enabled remote debugging in Chrome by running the following command in the terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down all instances of chrome and vscode, and then running the command with the remote-debug-port arg in your console.

Then open vscode, and try attach to chrome again.

Use the below config:

```
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      "urlFilter": "http://localhost:9222/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```